# How can I get my Parsing ATOM feed with SimpleXML (java) to return ellipsis instead of &#8230

Tags: java, rss, special-characters, atom-feed, simple-framework

I have a line of XML in my Atom feed (UTF-8) formatted with an ellipsis, like this.

```
<title type="html"><![CDATA[THIS WEEK IN HISTORY&#8230;]]></title>
```

To access the title, I call `title.getText()`.

- Actual result: `THIS WEEK IN HISTORY&#8230;`
- Expected result: `THIS WEEK IN HISTORY…`

Here's my `Title` class. What am I doing wrong with SimpleXML?

```
    public static class Title {

        @Attribute(name = "type", required = false)
        String type;
        @Text
        String text;

        public String getText() {
            return this.text;
        }

        void setText(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }

        public String getType() {
            return this.type;
        }

        public void setType(String _value) {
            this.type = _value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4()` from the Apache Commons Lang library

Comment: Didn't you need ... From &#8230; because escapeHtml4() does the reverse

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem is `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4("&#8230;")`

Hence giving the output as " ... "
[StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) provides with unescapeHtml4() to convert the [HTML Number to Symbol](http://ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) which is found in the [Jakarta Commons Lang Library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi)

unescapeHtml4() Unescapes a string containing entity escapes to a string containing the actual Unicode characters corresponding to the escapes. Supports HTML 4.0 entities.

Comment: Well that could actually contain all sorts of special characters I'm not prepared for. How could I tell SimpleXML to handle this better?

Comment: unescapeHtml() should be able to handle your normal text as well as the HTML number. Kindly elaborate the part "handling this better"

Comment: according to https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9992#comment:18  - if `type="html"` it should be formatted correctly. My code seems to be treating it as `type="text"`, which is the problem

Comment: Hmm maybe this is sorted out in the WordPress CDATA renderer but may be not in the way java reads it, how are you reading it

Comment: I'm reading it with SimpleXML, a XML parsing library that is also in java. Edit- using the Title.class above.